# how to change element function with js

Tags: javascript, html

i have a `<input type="text"/>` which is to perform two functions. Which function is executed is to be decided via a button. This button should toggle the onkeyup function. For this I used the following:

```
document.getElementById('input-search-tags').onkeyup = filter_tagsC()
```

but when I click the button, the function will not change.

Comment: You assigned the result of the function instead of the function. Remove `()` from the end.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle between which function fires `onkeyup` you need a click event listener on the button to set which function needs to be run.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const button = document.querySelector("button")

let functionState = "one"

const oneFunc = () => console.log("one")
const twoFunc = () => console.log("two")

input.onkeyup = oneFunc

const toggleFunctions = () => {
  if (functionState === "one") {
    input.onkeyup = twoFunc
    functionState = "two"
  } else {
    input.onkeyup = oneFunc
    functionState = "one"
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", toggleFunctions)
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Toggle function</button
</div>
```

With this example, I get both elements with `querySelector`.  Then I set a state value with `let` so that its value can be changed.  Then I define the 2 functions I want to toggle between.  I also set the `input` to have `onkeyup` of `oneFunc`, since the `functionState` starts as one.

Then I define a function that will assign a different function to `onkeyup` depending on the state of `functionState` and reset the `functionState` to the new value.  Lastly, I add an event listener to the button to run the `toggleFunctions` function on click.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify that you are calling a function onKeyUp and then specify that function's name:

```js
document.getElementById('input-search-tags').onkeyup = function() {filter_tagsC()}

function filter_tagsC() {
    // Your Code Here.
}
```

For an an easier method of handling onkeyup, I would suggest looking at the [keyup event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) method, as it is a bit more logical way of handling events. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is not the most straightforward solution. Why not just `.onkeyup = filter_tagsC`? The reason named functions exist in JavaScript is to allow you to do exactly this.

Comment: @msanford yeah fair that probably is a better way, I didn't think of that.